# Importing variables from another js file into a new js file React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is a beginner question, but I have a variable in a js file, React; and I want to use it in another JS file but exporting doesn't seem to work and it gives me an error because I have two export methods :

```
export default class Login
export var LoginToken = this.state.LoginToken

....
import {LoginToken} from './../../../../Components/Login/Login.js'

const headers = {
 Authorization: LoginToken
}

error: TypeError: undefined has no properties (export LoginToken part)
```

How should I import LoginToken variable?

Comment: Is there an `export default` somewhere in your file ? Can we see the error ? What's not working ? (Edit your question with those details)

Comment: @Treycos edited

Comment: The route you are importing `LoginToken` from might not be correct

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to export a state variable, you can't export an instance variable, the compiler needs to know the value of the exported members at compile time. It is not possible in this case because the `LoginToken` state variable is only initialized when you create a new object from your class.

You have to pass this variable as a prop to child components if they need to access it. If you want to make your token available throughout your app, you should look into the Context [API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). If you want to be able to access it outside of React components, then consider saving it to `localStorage` for example.